# With Rhino Mocks how do I intercept the call to a single property on an interface while passing everything else on to the “default implementation”?

Tags: .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have an interface IComplex with **many** methods and properties, I wish to create a “mock” that makes the “Config” property return an object of my choose, while passing all other calls onto a “real” instance of IComplex.

Just to make this a bit harder we are still using C# V2!

Comment: The solution I provided uses some C# 3.0 feature, but the main part is written in C# 2.0 anyway, so it would be easy to make it fully v2.0 compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a feature to configure many methods of mock at once. You need to specify all the methods to forward them to the other implementation...

... unless you write some reflection code to configure the mock.

Here is some (working) code. It uses C# 3.0, but the main part is "old style" Rhino Mocks stuff which had been written for C# 2.0.

```
public static class MockExtensions
{

    public static void ForwardCalls<T>(this T mock, T original)
    {
        mock.BackToRecord();
        Type mockType = typeof(T);
        var methods = mockType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Union(mockType.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)));
        foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
        {
            List<object> args = new List<object>();
            foreach (var arg in method.GetParameters())
            {
                args.Add(CreateDefaultValue(arg.ParameterType));
            }
            method.Invoke(mock, args.ToArray());
            var myMethod = method;
            if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            {
                LastCall
                    .IgnoreArguments()
                    // not Repeat.Any to allow overriding the value
                    .Repeat.Times(int.MaxValue)
                    .WhenCalled(call => myMethod.Invoke(original, call.Arguments));
            }
            else
            {
                LastCall
                    .IgnoreArguments()
                    // not Repeat.Any to allow overriding the value
                    .Repeat.Times(int.MaxValue)
                    .WhenCalled(call => call.ReturnValue = myMethod.Invoke(original, call.Arguments))
                    .Return(CreateDefaultValue(myMethod.ReturnType));
            }
        }
        mock.Replay();
    }

    private static object CreateDefaultValue(Type type)
    {

        if (type.IsValueType)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(null, type);
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass()
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IList<int>>();
        List<int> original = new List<int>();

        mock.ForwardCalls(original);

        mock.Add(7);
        mock.Add(8);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, mock.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(7, mock[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(8, mock[1]);

        //fake Count after ForwardCalls, use Repeat.Any()
        mock.Stub(x => x.Count)
            .Return(88)
            .Repeat.Any(); // repeat any needed to "override" value

        // faked count
        Assert.AreEqual(88, mock.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the `PartialMock` method to create a mock.**

You pass the type of the real class to this method and only register the calls that you need to mock.

Note that the methods you want to mock of the `IComplex` implementation need to be virtual to accomplish this.

See http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx for more information.

Comment: Thanks, however I need to pass an instance of the real type, as it is created by a "factory", so rhino-mocks can't just call it's contractor.    Also way does does the methods have to be virtaul, as I am using interfaces?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: a partial mock is a generated type which derives from the "real implementation". Like a normal derived class, it can only override the behavior of virtual members.

Comment: The problem is that Castle does have a `CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget`, but that's not used anywhere in the codebase of Rhino. This may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a proxy object which passes all calls through to an instance of the real implementation - except when you want to override behavior of a member.

As far as I know, Rhino Mocks does not support this. However, you might be able to build a mocking feature like that yourself with the [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) library. (Rhino mocks uses the same library.)